# Maxima and minina at the point of discontinuity

Tags: calculus

I am doing [this problem](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ProblemsNS/CalcI/MinMaxValues.aspx)  from Paul's Online Notes. Problem no is 13 on this link I posted. I have to come up with some function which satisfies following properties.

- (a) Graphed on the interval [2, 9]
- (b) Has a discontinuity at some point interior to the interval.
- (c) Has an absolute maximum at the discontinuity in part (b)
- (d) Has an absolute minimum at the discontinuity in part (b).

Now, I am having difficult time coming up with this function. How can we have absolute maxima and absolute minima at the same point unless we are talking about a constant function. But then there won't be any discontinuity there.

Comment: Does this mean that the left or right limit at the discontinuity point should be the maximum or minimum of all left or right limits? Like in no 4.

Comment: @Nils, I don't know how to interpret this question.

Comment: I think that's the only interpretation that makes sense. Everything else just doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Nils, All 4 conditions can not be satisfied at the same time. I will write to the people maintaining the site..

Comment: If you go to the Notes on your link, you'll see under Extreme Value Theorem that it seems to define the minima and maxima with the limits. There is an example image for this. However, it doesn't make sense according to his definition, in my opinion, because the value of the function at the discontinuity point is not actually defined in such a way that there can be a minimum and maximum at the same time.